# Passagem de Parâmentros de um fragment que utiliza json para outra fragment

Tags: java, android, json, fragment

Eu tenho uma tela que faz a busca pelo nome através de um EditText. E ao fazer a busca por nome ele me traz uma RecycleView com seus resultados. E quando eu toco em um elemento do resultado, ele vai para um fragment (outra tela). Só que eu queria passar o dado do elemento que foi tocado ao abrir a fragment (a fragment já abre, só não recebe os dados ainda). eu queria passar o campo "professor" para outra fragment. Alguém pode dar uma força ? Abaixo um trecho do Json com a chamada de fragment:

```
 public static consultarListaNome newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    consultarListaNome fragment = new consultarListaNome();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}


public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    progresso.hide();

    Curso curso = null;
    JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("curso"); // nome da tabela curso


    try {
        for(int i=0; i<json.length();i++){
            curso = new Curso();

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);

            curso.setNome(jsonObject.optString("nome"));
            curso.setProfessor(jsonObject.optString("professor"));
            curso.setCategoria(jsonObject.optString("categoria"));
            curso.setDado(jsonObject.optString("imagem"));
            listaCursos.add(curso);
        }

        progresso.hide();
        CursosAdapterImg adapter = new CursosAdapterImg(listaCursos,getContext(),this);
        recyclerCursos.setAdapter(adapter);

    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        progresso.hide();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Não foi possível listar os cursos " +response , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


}
```

Esse trecho abaixo chama a outra fragment:

```
@Override
public void onNoteClick(int position) {

    listaCursos.get(position);

    //Falta passar os parâmetros

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main,new consultarCursoUrl()).commit();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luciana, o correto seria a comunicação entre fragmentos ser feito pela Activity pai para que um fragmento não fique dependente do outro, e assim você poder reutiliza-lo sem problemas.
Mas se no seu caso não tiver problemas para este fragmento (que vai exibir o campo professor) ser dependente de outro, então você pode fazer da seguinte maneira.

```
@Override
public void onNoteClick(int position) {

    listaCursos.get(position);

    consultarCursoUrl fragmentConsulta = new consultarCursoUrl();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString( "nomeProfessor" , "João da Silva");
    fragmentConsulta.setArguments(arguments);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main,fragmentConsulta).commit();

}
```

E na seu fragmento `consultarCursoUrl` pode pegar esses dados assim:

```
Bundle arguments = getArguments();
String nomeProfessor = arguments.getString("nomeProfessor");
```

Caso queira saber sobre comunicação entre fragments utilizando a activity pai, da uma olhada [nesta matéria](https://www.androidpro.com.br/blog/desenvolvimento-android/fragments/#Comunicacaoentre_Fragments)

Comment: Não era bem o que eu queria, mas pelo menos já aprendi a passar parâmetros por fragments. Deu pra chegar perto.  Eu acho que me expliquei mal. Quando eu faço a busca, ele me retorna os itens no recycleview. O recycleview é composto por textview (la esta o campo professor) e de uma imagem. Dae me interessa levar um item desse textview.